# Expression: "die face-down in the muck"

Tags: idioms

What does "die face-down in the muck" mean, please?
Is it a very popular expression?

Comment: Do you have a context?

Comment: DONNY
Yeah Dude, why is Walter so pissed
off?

WALTER
Those rich fucks! This whole fucking
thing-- I did not watch my buddies
die face down in the muck so that
this fucking strumpet--

DUDE
I don't see any connection to Vietnam,
Walter.

WALTER
Well, there isn't a literal
connection, Dude.

Comment: This talk is of Walter Sobchak (Character) from The Big Lebowski movie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can probably tell from the dialogue of the movie, Dude does not understand the expression in context, or how it relates to the conversation either, if that tells you anything.

Dude takes it as literally referring to being killed and dying face down in the muck (laying face down in mud/swampy area) in the Vietnam War. Dude (and the viewer) assume he is talking about Vietnam because of the age of the characters would make them ~18 in the late 1960s, early 1970s, and often if you're talking about watching "buddies" dying, you're talking about a war. It also suggests a senseless, unceremonious death like they saw a lot of in Vietnam (as many - certainly the main characters in the movie - saw as a war America should never have engaged in.)

The next line

> DUDE
>                            Walter, face it, there isn't any 
>                            connection.

makes it clear Walter is just talking out of his ass (for lack of better terminology), being dramatic, and saying things that conjure up images of Vietnam because they tend to provoke an emotional response, but he doesn't really have a reason.

So the bottom line is it has a literal meaning, it just isn't really related to the rest of the conversation.

Comment: Well, Walter IS literally talking about people dying face down in the muck - it shouldn't be interpreted figuratively or in any other way. El Duderino understands it fine, it's just that it has nothing to do with the conversation everyone else is having.

Comment: @Matt fair point - edited my response a bit to make that clearer